# How to make a function as "press enter to continue" in C++?

Tags: c++

```
void wait_enter(){
    cout <<"\nPress any key to continue...";
    char key;
    cin >> key;
};
```

I've written a function for my program like this in order to make a stop, because in my program i open up a text file and they need time to read, but whenever i hit the button enter it just goes to the next line, or leave a space and hit enter, that doesnt count as a char it seems,

how can i imply pressing enter to this function? getchar() - cin.get() or cin.ignore() doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: By default, reading from `std::cin` using the `>>` operator will *skip* spaces. And newline (what the `Enter` key produces) is a space. Read about [the `std::skipws` and `std::noskipws` IO manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) for *one* way to solve your problem.

Comment: I think getch() will do the job as it waits for the user to press any key to resume

Comment: @Eatsamulhaq `getch` is not a standard C++ function.